# Difference between Require SSL and using URL Rewrite in IIS

Tags: iis, ssl, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

Is there improved security with web applications if you use "Require SSL" in the SSL Setting section of IIS? I was planning on creating a URL Rewrite rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*Require SSL*" will cause a `403.4 Forbidden` response if you try to access the site using `http://example.com`. It won't automatically redirect to the `https://` url.

This may be confusing for users if you're not linking in some way to the `https://example.com` SSL'd url.

If you want users to be able to randomly hit the site using plain `http://` and then redirect them to the SSL'd url then you're better off leaving "Require SSL" turned off and do a rewrite.

Comment: A URL rewrite is most likely what I am going to do. Trying to gather some technical facts before actually pursing that avenue so that our security audit requirements are met. I tried following this example, but I get a lock violation. Didn't realize that the server has IIS 8.5. http://www.jppinto.com/2009/04/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-iis-7/